# MapReduce Multiple Outputs: File Could Only Be Replicated to 0 Nodes, Instead of 1

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a Reduce job and I am getting the above error that the file could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of 1. I have searched online and saw that it could be a problem with the data node, but I am running other MapReduce jobs in this workflow that are all working. The only difference I see is that I am using multiple outputs and specifying a folder, but I am sure the path is correct. Here is the multiple outputs write line:

```java
mos.write("mosName", new LongWritable(key), value, outputFilePath);
```

The exact error that I am getting is:

```sh
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File xxx could 
only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 7 
datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue, which did not replicate when I was writing the output to context instead of MultipleOutputs. As far as I can tell it's caused by the fact that MultipleOutputs holds more data in memory longer.

The solution was a combination of:

(1) Performing compression on the output

```
FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);
```

(2) Giving my job more memory (keep in mind that JVM memory in java.opts has to be at most 80% of container memory)

```
-Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=3072 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx2048m
```